# A lightweight templateable WPF shape

Tags: wpf, templates, shapes

I'm using ellipses and other shapes as onscreen markers, I would like others to be able to change these visuals using templates. However, as shape doesn't support templating I'm forced to create a basic UserControl, which defaults to show an ellipse, and then use that instead of the basic shape.

Has anyone got a neater solution? I'm a little concerned if I create 1000's of these onscreen that performance/memory will be a bit of an overhead.

Comment: Did you get this working?  Can you give any details on your results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UserControl` derives from `ContentControl`.  It doesn't sounds as though you need content (the ability to host additional controls inside your shape), so I'd keep going up the hierarchy...

Here's a breakdown of the ancestry:

```
UserControl
    ContentControl
        Control
            FrameworkElement
                UIElement
                    Visual
                        ...
```

[`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx) defines the [`Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) property, so I think the lightest means of achieving what you want is to use `Control`:

```
<Control Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"/>
```

...and use a `Style` to set the template and any triggers/etc that you need.

If however you do need to host a child element inside your shape, you should use `ContentControl` thus:

```
<ContentControl Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"/>
```

If you find that this approach is too heavy-weight at runtime, then you might consider using [Shape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.aspx).

```
Shape
    FrameworkElement
        UIElement
            Visual
                ...
```

`Shape` does not inherit from `Control`, but rather directly from `FrameworkElement`.  It is not templateable.  It's an abstract class, of which you'd need to create your own custom subclass that knows how to describe its own presentation via the `DefiningGeometry` property.  This might be more complex than defining a style on a `Control`, but if you need the extra performance then you may have to go this route.

**EDIT** You might like to check out [DrawingVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254(VS.85).aspx) as well.  From MSDN:

> The DrawingVisual is a lightweight drawing class that is used to render shapes, images, or text. This class is considered lightweight because it does not provide layout or event handling, which improves its performance.

It also is not templateable, but if you need raw performance then it's worth a look.