# Optimize control templates for animating bindings

Tags: wpf, xaml, themes, controltemplate

Throughout our WPF application, we have many `Style`s with `ControlTemplate`s that need to animate `Binding` values. Since only `Freezable` values can take part in `Storyboard`s, we have to create multiple objects with different binding values and toggle their visibility in animations. Here's one of our buttons:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" To="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" To="Pressed"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderOver">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="IconUp">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="IconOver">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderOver">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="BorderDown">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="IconUp">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="IconOver">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="IconDown">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0.5"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="IconDisabled">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="IconUp">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="0"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="BorderOver" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Border x:Name="BorderDown" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Path x:Name="IconUp" Data="M14.077,9.772C11.634,9.772 9.652,11.753 9.652,14.197 9.652,16.641 11.634,18.622 14.077,18.622 16.521,18.622 18.502,16.641 18.502,14.197 18.502,11.753 16.521,9.772 14.077,9.772 M28,12L28,16 24.085,16C23.84,17.369,23.325,18.643,22.592,19.763L25.313,22.485 22.485,25.314 19.791,22.62C18.668,23.383,17.383,23.924,16,24.189L16,28 12,28 12,24.163C10.638,23.88,9.378,23.322,8.274,22.554L5.514,25.314 2.686,22.485 5.504,19.668C4.802,18.57,4.306,17.331,4.068,16L0,16 0,12 4.144,12C4.427,10.722,4.943,9.533,5.656,8.485L2.686,5.515 5.514,2.686 8.513,5.684C9.558,5,10.734,4.499,12,4.236L12,0 16,0 16,4.21C17.285,4.456,18.48,4.946,19.545,5.626L22.485,2.686 25.313,5.515 22.431,8.397C23.176,9.467,23.718,10.685,24.008,12z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="12" Width="12" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,4.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <Path x:Name="IconOver" Data="M14.077,9.772C11.634,9.772 9.652,11.753 9.652,14.197 9.652,16.641 11.634,18.622 14.077,18.622 16.521,18.622 18.502,16.641 18.502,14.197 18.502,11.753 16.521,9.772 14.077,9.772 M28,12L28,16 24.085,16C23.84,17.369,23.325,18.643,22.592,19.763L25.313,22.485 22.485,25.314 19.791,22.62C18.668,23.383,17.383,23.924,16,24.189L16,28 12,28 12,24.163C10.638,23.88,9.378,23.322,8.274,22.554L5.514,25.314 2.686,22.485 5.504,19.668C4.802,18.57,4.306,17.331,4.068,16L0,16 0,12 4.144,12C4.427,10.722,4.943,9.533,5.656,8.485L2.686,5.515 5.514,2.686 8.513,5.684C9.558,5,10.734,4.499,12,4.236L12,0 16,0 16,4.21C17.285,4.456,18.48,4.946,19.545,5.626L22.485,2.686 25.313,5.515 22.431,8.397C23.176,9.467,23.718,10.685,24.008,12z" Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Height="12" Width="12" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,4.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Path x:Name="IconDown" Data="M14.077,9.772C11.634,9.772 9.652,11.753 9.652,14.197 9.652,16.641 11.634,18.622 14.077,18.622 16.521,18.622 18.502,16.641 18.502,14.197 18.502,11.753 16.521,9.772 14.077,9.772 M28,12L28,16 24.085,16C23.84,17.369,23.325,18.643,22.592,19.763L25.313,22.485 22.485,25.314 19.791,22.62C18.668,23.383,17.383,23.924,16,24.189L16,28 12,28 12,24.163C10.638,23.88,9.378,23.322,8.274,22.554L5.514,25.314 2.686,22.485 5.504,19.668C4.802,18.57,4.306,17.331,4.068,16L0,16 0,12 4.144,12C4.427,10.722,4.943,9.533,5.656,8.485L2.686,5.515 5.514,2.686 8.513,5.684C9.558,5,10.734,4.499,12,4.236L12,0 16,0 16,4.21C17.285,4.456,18.48,4.946,19.545,5.626L22.485,2.686 25.313,5.515 22.431,8.397C23.176,9.467,23.718,10.685,24.008,12z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="12" Width="12" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,4.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Opacity="0"/>
                        <Path x:Name="IconDisabled" Data="M14.077,9.772C11.634,9.772 9.652,11.753 9.652,14.197 9.652,16.641 11.634,18.622 14.077,18.622 16.521,18.622 18.502,16.641 18.502,14.197 18.502,11.753 16.521,9.772 14.077,9.772 M28,12L28,16 24.085,16C23.84,17.369,23.325,18.643,22.592,19.763L25.313,22.485 22.485,25.314 19.791,22.62C18.668,23.383,17.383,23.924,16,24.189L16,28 12,28 12,24.163C10.638,23.88,9.378,23.322,8.274,22.554L5.514,25.314 2.686,22.485 5.504,19.668C4.802,18.57,4.306,17.331,4.068,16L0,16 0,12 4.144,12C4.427,10.722,4.943,9.533,5.656,8.485L2.686,5.515 5.514,2.686 8.513,5.684C9.558,5,10.734,4.499,12,4.236L12,0 16,0 16,4.21C17.285,4.456,18.48,4.946,19.545,5.626L22.485,2.686 25.313,5.515 22.431,8.397C23.176,9.467,23.718,10.685,24.008,12z" Fill="#FF999999" Height="12" Width="12" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,4.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Opacity="0"/>

                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="4.5,1,21,1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

These buttons are used with `DynamicResources`es. Like this:

```
<Button Content="..." Style="{DynamicResource hkbtnSettings}" Background="{DynamicResource InterfaceHeaderColor}" Foreground="{DynamicResource InterfaceBodyColor}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource InterfaceAccentColor}"/>
```

We are having some rendering performance issues in our application. I was wondering if we could optimize these templates in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Avoid Use Of Dynamic resource** : Please refer this [Link](http://miteshsureja.blogspot.in/2011/10/static-vs-dynamic-resources-in-wpf.html)

Dynamic resource has more performance overhead than static resources because it look up for resources every time it requested or needed.

2)**Trigger vs. Visual States** :Please refer this [Link](http://www.centigrade.de/en/blog/article/wpf-performance-2/)

Every visual state change starts up a storyboard that in turn contains further timeline objects. Naturally this consumes more time and memory than simply setting a property in a trigger

3)**Shape vs Control** Please refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564404/a-lightweight-templateable-wpf-shape)

we can not add child element to shape hence it is lighter than control...hence in example I used Rectangle instead of Border.

4) **x:Name vs Name** Please refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589874/in-wpf-what-are-the-differences-between-the-xname-and-name-attributes)

Replace  x:Name With "Name" In template.

5)**Avoid supplying Unnecessary "name" attributes**: Please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100007/not-specifying-control-names-in-wpf-performance-effect)

In example I removed grid name.

6)**Optimize element count** please refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/hh994641.aspx)

The XAML  can display thousands of objects, and you can make your template layout and render scenes faster by reducing the number of elements in template.

---

Final template after considering all these points

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Grid>
            <Rectangle Name="Rectangle" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
            <Path Name="Icon" Data="M14.077,9.772C11.634,9.772 9.652,11.753 9.652,14.197 9.652,16.641 11.634,18.622 14.077,18.622 16.521,18.622 18.502,16.641 18.502,14.197 18.502,11.753 16.521,9.772 14.077,9.772 M28,12L28,16 24.085,16C23.84,17.369,23.325,18.643,22.592,19.763L25.313,22.485 22.485,25.314 19.791,22.62C18.668,23.383,17.383,23.924,16,24.189L16,28 12,28 12,24.163C10.638,23.88,9.378,23.322,8.274,22.554L5.514,25.314 2.686,22.485 5.504,19.668C4.802,18.57,4.306,17.331,4.068,16L0,16 0,12 4.144,12C4.427,10.722,4.943,9.533,5.656,8.485L2.686,5.515 5.514,2.686 8.513,5.684C9.558,5,10.734,4.499,12,4.236L12,0 16,0 16,4.21C17.285,4.456,18.48,4.946,19.545,5.626L22.485,2.686 25.313,5.515 22.431,8.397C23.176,9.467,23.718,10.685,24.008,12z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Height="12" Width="12" Stretch="Fill" Margin="0,0,4.5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            <ContentPresenter Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="4.5,1,21,1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Rectangle" Property="Opacity" Value="1"></Setter>
                <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=BorderBrush,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="Rectangle" Property="Opacity" Value="1"></Setter>
                <Setter TargetName="Rectangle" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=BorderBrush,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"></Setter>
                <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Fill" Value="{Binding Path=Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.5"></Setter>
                <Setter TargetName="Icon" Property="Fill" Value="#FF999999"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

---

**Some Other usefull links**

1)http://www.centigrade.de/en/blog/article/wpf-performance-2/

2)http://wpftutorial.net/10PerformanceTips.html

Comment: A great collection of tips. I didn't know about number 5 in particular. Just: For a rich UI, we need smooth transitions so we can't use setters. And since the UI is skinnable, use of DynamicResources is mandatory. So how can we optimize our template preserving the transition animations?

Comment: we can use animation in trigger like this http://prntscr.com/5l2i6h and other optimising methods I have already provided that I know.

Comment: So in order to have animations, we have to have 4 path objects instead of one? (Since we can't use binding in storyboards)

Comment: Yes to use animation we have to have 4 path objects.